# Yii Framework, reduce page loading time due to massive data in sql table

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have a table that contains more than 15k rows of records.

I'm pulling out the data and displaying it in a jquery datatable plugin but it took like few minutes to display. Any suggestions how to reduce the page load time?

This is how I extract data in the Controller.

```
$model = Property::model->with('estates','types','tenures','rooms','districts')->findAll();
$this->render('index', compact('models','pages'));
```

Comment: 1) Use caching 2) Extract only as many rows as you are displaying each time. If that's not possible, load the first 1000 or whatever, and get the rest asynchronously.

Comment: Should I use the database caching method together with the ActiveRecord?

Comment: Thanks @Ansari. I think the only way is to use pagination and load rows of record by 10 each.

Comment: Yes in Yii you can cache the result of a database query (or an ActiveRecord findAll() query).

Comment: why do you need to pull out 15,000 rows? Why don't you use paging or infinite scrolling?

Comment: I intend to display all the 15,000 rows inside a datatable plugin to save on the pagination and search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pagination and just omit "with", that way the records will be eagerly loaded, so only those needed to display would actually be in cache. Give it a try and you'll see immediate difference.

Comment: Thanks. It works better in terms of performance although I have to add several more functions rather than having to enjoy the jquery datatable plugin.